# Paste source link with copied text

Tags: copy-paste

When I copy text from a website, I would like the url of the original site to be included when I paste it. This is possible when pasting into Evernote, indicating that macOS indeed captures the source url upon copying. This is especially important for citations, but in general is helpful for keeping track of sources.

Ideally I’d have the option to paste with or without source link.

Solution could be an alternative pasteboard app, a script, a setting, etc.

**Is there a way to copy and paste the source url when copying text?**

Comment: In what app? Apple apps do it. Try right click, copy link from this question title & paste to TextEdit. ..or do you mean you want it to gather up the page url when you copy regular text?

Comment: OneNote does this when you clip text to your note

Comment: @Tetsujin when I copy and paste text I’d like to _also_ paste the url

Comment: @Allan This, and Evernote, makes me think the clipboard standardly captures this data – I don’t assume OneNote is some how backtracing the clipboard, unless it only works when OneNote is open _before_ you copy

Comment: That’s an incorrect assumption.  The clipboard doesn’t capture the source.  The web clipper in OneNote or Evernote  is a completely different tool and doesn’t use the system  clipboard whatsoever.